# How to get multiple occurences of an element with XPath under usage of normalize-space and substring-before

Tags: xpath

I have an element with three occurences on the page. If i match it with Xpath expression `//div[@class='col-md-9 col-xs-12']`, i get all three occurences as expected.

Now i try to rework the matching element on the fly with

1. `substring-before(//div[@class='col-md-9 col-xs-12'], 'Bewertungen')`, to get the string before the word "Bewertungen",
2. `normalize-space(//div[@class='col-md-9 col-xs-12'])`, to clean up redundant whitespaces,
3. `normalize-space(substring-before(//div[@class='col-md-9 col-xs-12']` - both actions.

The problem with last three expressions is, that **they extract only the first occurence** of the element. It makes no difference, whether i add `/text()` after matching definition.

I don't understand, how an addition of `normalize-space` and/or `substring-before` influences the "main" expression in the way it stops to recognize multiple occurences of targeted element and gets only the first. Without an addition it matches everything as it should.

How is it possible to adjust the Xpath expression nr. 3 to get all occurences of an element?

Example url is https://www.provenexpert.com/de-de/jazzyshirt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both `normalize-space()` and `substring-before()` have a required cardinality of 1, meaning  can only accept one occurrence of the element you are trying to normalize or find a substring of. Each of your expressions results in 3 sequences which these two functions cannot process. (I probably didn't express the problem properly, but I think this is the general idea).

In light of that, try:

```
//div[@class='col-md-9 col-xs-12']/substring-before(normalize-space(.), 'Bewertung')
```

Comment: It looks, like it should work, but it doesn't work for me... I use it in a kind of environment, where Java-flavoured Xpath is in use - and i can't get this expression through validation. Could you imagine how the syntax of this expression could be adjusted?

Comment: Thats the problem - i get only an error message fired by environment, like "invalid expression". In general there is Java-flavored Xpath 1.0.

Comment: I see; so it doesn't tell you if the expression is xpath-invalid or java-invalid? That obviously makes a difference...

Comment: This environment has its own syntax validation engine. And looks like it just doesn't understand the expression. If i modify your expression to `//div[@class='col-md-9 col-xs-12'][substring-before(normalize-space(.), 'Bewertung')] - it becomes valid, but obviously doesn't work...
` Testing other things i realized it has problems with the syntax part `(normalize-space(.)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like an xpath 1.0 vs 2.0 issue. This expression uses the `/` path operator in a way that, as Michael Kay mentioned, is only available from xpath 2.0. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_2.0#Path_expressions.

Comment: You are right. It is a tool issue, what i experience here:( Can something like `[1]` be used with my expression `normalize-space(substring-before(//div[@class='col-md-9 col-xs-12']`? So i would be able to setup: extract only the first occurence, or the second...

Answer (score 1):

Note that in XPath 1.0, functions like `substring-after()`, if given a set of three nodes as input, ignore all nodes except the first. XPath 2.0 changes this: it gives you an error.

In XPath 3.1 you can apply a function to each of the nodes using the apply operator, "!": `//div[condition] ! substring-before(normalize-space(), 'Bewertung')`. That returns a sequence of 3 strings. There's no equivalent in XPath 1.0, because there's no data type in XPath 1.0 that can represent a sequence of strings.

In XPath 2.0 you can often achieve the same effect using "/" instead of "!", but it has restrictions.

When asking questions on StackOverflow, please always mention which version of XPath you are using. We tend to assume that if people don't say, they're probably using 1.0, because 1.0 products don't generally advertise their version number.

Comment: Unfortunately it is Xpath 1.0. But i wonder about your statement `there's no data type in XPath 1.0 that can represent a sequence of strings`. My first expression, `//div[@class='col-md-9 col-xs-12']`, successfully extracted the full sequence of elements. Or do i misunderstand something?

Comment: XPath 1.0 can return a set of nodes from the source document, but it can't return a set of strings.